# date difference between 2 records of same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
    table A             
       id     date1 date2       
row1    1   20170501    20170601        
row2    1   20170501    99991231        
row3    1   20170502    20170504        
row4    1   20170501    20170604        
row5    2   20170501    20170605        
row6    2   20170501    20170506
```

I have a change to be done and this is it. I tried using etl but the results are not satisfactory.

date1 of current row( row1) is compared to the date2 of next record ( row2) if the difference is >2 days(+ positve) then get that date only along with that id.
in this case row 2 is the date(i.e date 2 of row2) and this must be running till it finds the date and if it doesn’t find any select must not pick up that record.
note we have to order by descending for date 1 on basis of id column and then start comparing(date 2 value defaulted to 99991231 for 99999999)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I would urge you to read this explanation and see if you think you would be able to answer this based only on the information posted here. You also need to define "next record". By definition a table is an unordered set. Do you have something you can use to define the order? Here is a great place to start for ideas on improving this question. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: lead, lag, or cte with row_number(). Read what @SeanLange wrote as well as what these functions do

Answer (score 0):

The given query will give you for a given date1 the datediff with the following date2 (in days).

```
SELECT id,date1
,DATEDIFF(day,date1,LEAD(date2) OVER (ORDER BY id ASC, date1 DESC)) as [DayDiff]
FROM [table A]
```

Then you only have to store into a temporary table and filter for days above 2.

```
SELECT * FROM #tempTb WHERE [DayDiff] > 2
```